# TypeRocket middleware verify token

Tags: php, wordpress

**TypeRocket v4 as mu-plugin on Wordpress 5.2 - PHP 7.3**

Trying to submit a simple form with nonce field. I get into the route file, but when I try to forward to the controller I get `Invalid CSRF Token`

**route:**

```
tr_route()->match('purchase')->post()->do('addPurchase@Purchase');
```

I checked the POST data and that looks fine. The nonce field checks out as well. Why is it not forwarding to my controller?

Comment: Are you using the tr_nonce_field() ?

Comment: @Kevin - No I am not. I used regular HTML form elements. I did try to generate a form in my typerocket view through `$form = tr_form()`, but I fail to understand how to get a correct form. I come as far as the form tags, but field tags seem to fail. In the view I don't seem to have access to the libraries responsible for creating field. Do I create the form with fields inside the view?
Thank you for reaching out!

Comment: @Kevin - I got a bit further with this issue. The `tr_nonce_field()` did the trick. I also understand better what you do in the backend with `$form = tr_form()`... Yet It is a step, but I am not there. Since it is a different issue, I opened another Question: TypeRocket Form Elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeRocket has a native form generator that creates a hidden field

**example:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

The value of the request method is generated by the choice of form.
When using this form generator, it also generates the `nonce field`.

I am having problems with this form generator, which is another question [TypeRocket Form Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599976/typerocket-form-elements)

For **hand typed HTML forms** you can add the hidden field to the form to control the form request method if you want to use anything else than POST.
Add the nonce field:

```
<?php echo tr_nonce_field(); ?>
```