# TypeRocket Form Elements

Tags: wordpress

**TypeRocket v4 as mu-plugin on Wordpress 5.2 - PHP 7.3**

I am having issues with creating a form using TypeRocket (v4)

```
<?php
    $form = tr_form('purchase', 'create');
    echo $form->open();
    // echo $form->field("Author");
    echo $form->close('Submit');
?>
```

Sending the form in this condition it will pass. When I uncomment field 'Author', I get ..

`Argument 1 passed to TypeRocket\Elements\Form::field() must be an instance of TypeRocket\Elements\Fields\Field, string given`

Why can I not just generate fields in TypeRocket view? What am I missing?
I tried to understand this, but fail ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `text` instead of `field`

```
<?php
    $form = tr_form('purchase', 'create');
    echo $form->open();
    echo $form->text("Author");
    echo $form->close('Submit');
?>
```

Comment: I used the code stated above exactly as is and I get an error when rendering the page. `Method TypeRocket\Elements\Fields\Text::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Error: Call to a member function getFillableFields() on null` . That is where I get confused. Do I miss a hook with a library?

Comment: bump. The solution provided is not working. Would there be an error in the back-end of TypeRocket?

Comment: Do you have a model named `Purchase`?